# Confusion regarding comparison operators in std::min, std::max

Tags: c++, max, min, comparison-operators

`std::min` and `std::max` allows custom comparators, but I am a bit confused on how the ordering works.

Consider the following:

```
   int i = 1;
   int j = 2;

   auto min_val = min(i, j, [](const auto val1, const auto val2){
      if(val1 < val2) return true;
      return false;
   });
```

This returns the minimum value, which is `i`. But I don't understand why we use the `<` instead of the `>`, and why `val1` and `val2` appear on the left and right of the operand, respectively.

Consider the following:

```
   int i = 1;
   int j = 2;

   auto max_val = max(i, j, [](const auto val1, const auto val2){
      if(val1 > val2) return true;
      return false;
   });
```

I was thinking that this would return the maximum value, but it actually returns the minimum value, and again, we must use the `<` operand. Could someone explain what is going on beneath the hood?

I've run into this issue on some other stuff too, I think with `std::priority_queue` and `std::map`, where the ordering and comparison operators aren't very intuitive to me, and most times I have to guess and check to get what I want.

Comment: If you're confused, or don't remember, consult the reference.  cppreference is quite clear on the expectations of the functor.  See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max

Comment: @NathanOliver I actually did look at cpprefernce for min and max, but there is a typo on one of them because the functor is described identically for both.

Comment: That is not a typo. It's supposed to be like that.

Comment: as Timo said, it's not a typo. Both function excepts true to be returned of the first parameter is less then the second.  You can code both the min and max functions with a comparator like that.

Comment: @Timo  oh then I guess this is exactly what I found out with the snippets in my OP. I think my confusion is how the function treats the return value from the functor, which I don't think is described on the site.

Comment: It's a convention.  If you pass your functor using `>` to `std::min()` then `std::min()` will return the maximum value.   Which probably achieves little more than confusing mere mortals reading your code.   Probably more useful for `std::sort()`, where passing a comparator that uses `<` (or `std::less`) is the default, and results in sorting in ascending order, but passing one that uses `>` instead sorts in descending order.

Comment: @NathanOliver That seems to be what I realized from the snippets in the OP, but how do I know how a particular function treats the return value from the functor? In this case, how do I know that if the functor returns true if `lhs < rhs` then that `std::min` and `std::max` will output the minimum and maximum value, respectively?

Comment: It says it right on the reference page *comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare) which returns ​true if a is less than b.*

Comment: @NathanOliver No, I understand that. I was asking about something else, but looking at the "second version" under possible implementation answered my question.

Comment: `min()` gives you what would be the first element if you sorted the given arguments.  `max()` gives you the last one. If you check out how `sort()` works, this will make sense. For that, all of them use `less()` as predicate by default. If you now use the opposite predicate, ordering is inversed and the first element will be the maximum. Further cases are `map` and `set`, which use `less` for ordering by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That basically boils down to how those functions are defined in the standard. [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max), for example, defines the comparer (your lambda) as follows:

> comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare) which returns ​true if a is less than b.

Usually, when it comes to the order of values within the c++ standard library, it's (almost?) always `std::less` that is used as a default comparer, which does exactly `left < right`.

As to why it's always `a < b` that has to be satisfied I think it's simply to reduce coding overhead if you were to write it yourself. Imagine having a comparer like this:

```
struct MyComp
{
    bool operator()(MyType a, MyType b) const
    {
        return a.getValue() < b.getValue();
    }
};
```

Since all the constructs in the standard library require your comparer to return true, if `a < b`, you can use one simple comparer for a multitude of constructs. E.g.

```
auto maxVal = std::max(a, b, MyComp{});
auto minVal = std::min(a, b, MyComp{});
std::map<MyType, MyComp> myMap;
```

will all just work with one comparer.